# Mysql join same table where not in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table like this

```
id  original    alias  lang
1   word1es     word1   es
2   word1en     word1   en
3   word2es     word2   es
4   word2fr     word2   fr
5   word3es     word3   es
```

Considering `es` as master lang
I need to retrieve all entryes (based on `alias` column) that exists in `es` language but not in others languages

Espected result:

```
alias  lang
word1   fr
word2   en
word3   en
word3   fr
```

I have tried

```
SELECT B.alias, B.lang FROM my_table A
JOIN my_table B
ON B.alias NOT IN (A.alias)


SELECT B.alias, B.lang FROM my_table AS A
JOIN my_table AS B
ON
A.alias = B.alias
WHERE
B.alias IS NULL


SELECT B.alias, B.lang FROM my_table A
JOIN my_table B
ON A.alias <> B.alias
```

But none does not return the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a list of all langs can help:

```
SELECT esWords.*, langs.lang 
FROM my_table AS esWords
/* join with all other language identifiers to simulate a 
   "what is it in this language?" question
*/
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT lang FROM my_table) AS langs 
   ON esWords.lang <> langs.lang
/* left join with my_table again to find the words for other languages */
LEFT JOIN my_table AS otherWords 
   ON esWords.alias = otherWords.alias
   AND langs.lang = otherWords.lang
WHERE esWords.lang = 'es' 
   AND otherWords.id IS NULL /* filter out all languages where a 
                                word was found for that language
                              */
```

Technically, you don't need to filter out the original language in the first join; since it will always have a match, the final `otherWords.id IS NULL` will always filter it out.

Comment: Thank you ... that work. Only a little typo `WHERE esTbl.lang = 'es' ` must be `WHERE esWords.lang = 'es' ` ... I have made a fiddle here http://rextester.com/AXN18476

Comment: Yeah, I used a different alias when I started working on it; corrected the typo for future references.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where t.lang = 'es' and
      not exists (select 1 from my_table t2 where t2.alias = t.alias and t2.lang <> 'es');
```

Another approach uses aggregation:

```
select alias, max(lang)
from my_table
group by alias
having min(lang) = max(lang) and min(lang) = 'es';
```

If the only language is `es`, then this will return that alias.

Comment: Thank you for answering but both return the new entryes on `es` language ... I want all others ... where new `es` entries not exists but +1 because still can be useful for me for other query